# Unable to search one variable within another variable using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Using perl, i'm unable to perform a simple search to see if one number is within another.  The below example doesn't enter the if statement.

```
my $a = "12345";
my $b = "123456789";
if($a=~ m/$b/g) #doesn't work
{
    print "success";
}
```

The below doesn't work either.

```
my $a = "12345";
my $b = "123456789";
if($a =~ /$b/) #doesn't work
{
    print "success";
}
```

Comment: if you want to check if `$a` is in `$b`, use `$b =~ m/$a/` (`g` flag is not needed)

Comment: thats a little non-intuitive, but it worked....thanks!  I switched to using the index searching instead.

Comment: that is hardly non-intuitive... suppose you didn't use a variable, it would be  `$b =~ m/12345/` ... and for search and replace, it is `$b =~ s/12345/abc/` .. so the take away is `variable =~` to match or search and replace on that variable

Comment: Please avoid using special vars `$a` and `$b`.

Comment: Or just single letter variable names in general.

Answer (score 3):

To check if `$substr` is in `$string`, you want:

```
if ($string =~ /\Q$substr\E/)
```

or

```
if (index($string, $substr) >= 0)
```

In your case, that means

```
if ($b =~ /\Q$a\E/)
```

or

```
if (index($b, $a) >= 0)
```

---

`\Q..\E` causes the contents of the variable in between to be matched literally rather than have it treated as a regex pattern.

`if (//g)` makes no sense, and using it can produce subtle and very odd problems.

Answer (score 0):

There are characters that may have different meanings in regular expressions. Instead, do this:

```
if (index($b, $a) != -1) #works
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might have mixed up your variables in the statement.  The $a =~ m/$b/g indicates that $b can be found in $a (in order to be true), not the $a can be found in $b.  Since $a is less in length than $b, the statements fail ( since 123456789 cannot be found in 12345).

I suspect what you want is:

```
if ( $b =~ m/$a/g )  # or ( $b =~ /$a/ )
{
  print "success";
}
```

Comment: `if ( //g )` makes no sense, and you didn't convert `$a` into a pattern using `quotemeta`.